# PromQL searching for an epoch

Tags: prometheus, promql

We have a metric `activation_time` that returns an epoch of a start time. For example, 1689550299110. This metric is initialized on application start and is always exposed with the same value.

Is there a way to get all metrics, values of which is less than current epoch time minus 2 months or something.

We have an application that gets slow over time and we want to create alert when app wasn't restarted in a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare metric value with result of function [`time()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#time).

Since value of your metric appears to contain timestamp in milliseconds ([against OpenMetrics recommendations](https://github.com/OpenObservability/OpenMetrics/blob/main/specification/OpenMetrics.md#timestamps)) you should divide it by 1000 to convert to seconds.

Your final query might be something like `activation_time/1000 < time() - 60 * 24 * 60 * 60` or `floor((activation_time/1000 - time()) / 24 / 60 / 60) > 60` depending on what you want to show in your alert; only difference is value of returned result: former will return timestamp of start (in seconds), latter - difference between timestamp of start and current moment, in days.

Example of alert rule:

```yaml
- alert: WasNotRestartedLately 
  expr: floor((activation_time/1000 - time()) / 24 / 60 / 60) > 60
  annotations:
    summary: Application hasn't been restarted for {{ $value }} days
```